# login user and authenticate that but on mixin other app cant get user login

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Please help me for problem
I develop website via django-rest-framework and reactjs
On backend code

below code on app api

```
import json

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

def login_view(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    username = data.get('username')
    password = data.get('password')

    if username is None or password is None:
        return JsonResponse({'detail': 'Please provide username and password.'}, status=400)

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is None:
        return JsonResponse({'detail': 'Invalid credentials.'}, status=400)

    login(request, user)
    return JsonResponse({'detail': 'Successfully logged in.'})
```

below code on other app and i want get user login mixin but on mixin return AnonymousUser

```
class driverapi(storekeeperMixin,viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        driverslist = driver.object.all()
        serilizer = OBJdriver(driverslist, many=True)
        return Response(serilizer.data)

class storekeeperMixin():
    def dispatch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        print('****************************' + str(request.user.username))
```

Comment: It is not an issue with Mixin. It has to do with they way you have authenticated. If you use cookie based authentication, then you need to share cookie information with the server from reactjs.